# WebDriverWait for Selenium Webdriver -Wait code

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, wait

Into Visual Studio for Selenium Webdriver...

This code get error arguments, can someone help me please?

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); 
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("signin-email")));
```

See the capture:
http://s28.postimg.org/s416s3zwd/OCTAVO.jpg

Comment: your error is for `WebDriverWait` constructor itself, its expecting `System.Timespan` instead of `int` as the second argument. And what language is it in error message .. Spanish ?

Comment: ref: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm for webdriver `C#` API and correct your constructor and `until` method, seems you referred API specs for java

Comment: the code i put above in for java then? (sorry for the question)

Comment: thats ok, use webdriver for c# and code in C#, hope you will not face (although inevitable :)) further issues.

Comment: capture result: http://s14.postimg.org/ro5fp7741/NOVENO.jpg the 1 WebDriverWait line is correct but no the second..

Comment: please refer the link in my second comment and see what Until expects there, or is there any other equivalent for java's until there. You are at your own now :), may be some one savvy in C# can help you.

Comment: Ahm, this other code line is correct for C# but it does not wait any second really in the practise... driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

Comment: Ok, I will search more, thanks a lot Shail, have a good wednesday!

Comment: I don't discriminate every day is a good day.